# How do I find the formula here?

Tags: calculus

There are a row of digits 6 4 2 0 0 2 4 6 . There are also correspondig numbers to each of them: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

How do we find which formula to use, in order to get the digits, knowing their number?

For example for the first four digits it could be possible to use y=8-2n.
But we need a formula where we would get 0 both from 4 and 5...

Comment: You don't.  One formula migt match fo 8 numbers.  Another formula might also match for the same eight numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

$$6 \ 4 \  2 \  0 \  0 \  2 \  4 \  6$$
is symmetric in nature.

1. What type of function would ***absolutely*** (hint hint) allow you to convert
   $$1 \ 2 \  3 \  4 \  5 \  6 \  7 \  8$$
   to a symmetric row of numbers first?

   > The absolute function: $|x|$
2. What is the number (not necessarily integer) right in the middle of the input row?

   > The median: $4.5$
3. What functions convert real numbers to an integer nearby?

   > The floor and ceiling functions

Spoiler:

> $$y=2\times\left\lfloor|x-4.5|\right\rfloor$$

Comment: Thank you. You are a genius! I thought of |х| , but I wouldn't figure out that I need to use floor function in order to get the formula. Thank you again!